# How to deploy site to VPS from Github by SFTP with password (no keys)?

Tags: sftp, github-actions

I found many instructions on the net, but all are based on SSH keys. My SSH is based on keys only, but I created another user account just for SFTP with login and password.

I can login to SFTP easilly via FileZilla directly to website directory with no keys.

I tried Github Marketplace Actions but none worked because connections where rejected (no keys) even I passed password.

Do you know any working solution?

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but my webhoster only supports SFTP, so i had to look for the same thing and landed here.

I ended up with [ftp-deployer](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/ftp-deployer), which has the attribute `sftp`, that can be set to `true`.

I also tried [sftp-ssh-action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/sftp-ssh-action), it also works, but has no option to exclude files or paths.